# troubles with a simple logger

Tags: c++, logging

I am trying to create a simple logging class with just static methods but i get troubles when i try to log some `const char*` variable and wonder why. It says `Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type`. I looked for it at stackoverflow and google but somehow it doesn't help me to get it right.
The logging methods are this:

```
void Logger::log(const char* message){
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::cout<< "[INFO]" << message << std::endl;
#endif
}

void Logger::err(const char* message){
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::cout << "[ERROR]" << message << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

And i am trying to call them here:

```
char* Config::getConfigValue(const char* name){
    if (m_doc.first_node())
    {
        xml_node<>* node = m_doc.first_node()->first_node(name);
        if (node)
        {
            Logger::log("Getting value: " + name + ": "+ node->value());
            return node->value();
        }
    }
    Logger::log("Getting value: " + name + " FAILED!");
    return 0;
}
```

Am i totaly wrong with the idea of such a simple logger?

And should i do `#ifdef` at every point where i log or can i do it like this?

For any hints to solve this issue and to help me to get a "good" logger i would be greatful.

Comment: The expression `"Getting value: " + name + ": "+ node->value()` is hardly a `char const *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your logging. You cannot concatenate `C` strings using `+`.

```
"Getting value: " + name // Not going to work.
```

If you are in `c++` anyways, I would stick with `std::string` when possible because that one **does** support `+` for concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

`char *` or `char const *` is a pointer type, not a class or struct, thus does not support concatenation using `+` operator.

You're using C++, so use the C++ way of handling strings : replace `const char *` with `const std::string &`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

"Getting value: " + name + " FAILED!"

where name is `const char* name` is an error because there is no operator+ in global namespace that takes `const char*`. You have to use `strcat`, `strcpy`, etc.

In C++ you should use `std::string` which is very flexible ( i.e resizes dynamically):

```
char* Config::getConfigValue( std::string name){
    //...
    Logger::log("Getting value: " + name + ": "+ node->value());
}
```